# how can i get ajax requestion status code and response data at phpunit + selenium test platform?

Tags: javascript, php, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phpunit

please ask it, how to get ajax request status code and response data?

```
$capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'chrome');

$this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
$this->webDriver->get('http://www.test.com/login');
$username = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('name'));
$username->clear();
$username->sendKeys('admin');

$password = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('password'));
$password->sendKeys('1234567');
//send ajax request
$this->webDriver->executeScript('loginSub()');
$this->assertEquals('username or password error.', $this->getAlertText());

$password->clear();
$password->sendKeys('123456');
//send ajax request
$this->webDriver->executeScript('loginSub()');
```

how to get ajax callback function variable "data" and "response" in php?

```
//javascript code
$.post('/login', {'name':name, 'password':password}, function(data,statusText, response){

    //how to get the variable "data" and "response" in php ?

    console.log(response.status);
},"json");
```

the follow code is my way to assert login success.

```
try {
    $element = $this->getElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.layui-layer-page .layui-layer-content'));
    $this->assertEquals('login success', $element->getText());
} catch (NoSuchElementException $e) {
    //is anything i should to do here?
    print_r('timeout');
}

sleep(2);
$this->webDriver->executeScript("common.showMessage(200, 'test finish, the broswer will close in a sec.')");
sleep(4);
$this->webDriver->close();
```

get the element after ajax request.

```
private function getElement(WebDriverBy $webDriverBy)
{
    static $count = 0;
    try {
        return $this->webDriver->findElement($webDriverBy);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException $e) {
        $count++;
        sleep(1);
    }
    if ($count > 5) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException($webDriverBy->getValue());
    }
    return $this->getElement($webDriverBy);
}
```